# multiple sessions accessing the dataset & updating the same record

Tags: .net, asp.net

Please let me know how to achieve this synchronization between the data while updating the same record using datasets.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What errors did you see? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only one thread on your pool, and your update/read happends in milliseconds, you do not need to do anything, and database take care of this synchronization.

If you use more than one thread on your pool, and your process takes too much time to complete, you can use [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to synchronize them

If you use more than one server, you need to use a common directory, or database, with mutex together to lock and unlock process all together to all computers.